# Manipulate Demo Full Screen

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, options

Is it possible to create a demo using `Manipulate` and then open it in a document that can be expanded to full screen?

Comment: Try: Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> Full], {a, 0, 2}]

Comment: btw you always can hit F12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stealing Lou's example, you can add a couple of options:

```
CreateDocument[
      Manipulate[ Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}, ImageSize -> Full], {a, 0, 2}],
      CellMargins -> 0,
      ShowCellBracket -> False,
      WindowSize -> Full]
```

If you want those options to be always valid, you can put `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],...]` into `Initialization` of `Manipulate` too.

Comment: I've got some ideas from you "shared" in my work. +1